# How to understand `C.super[P]` in scala?

Tags: scala, types, super

I'm reading the book of "The depth of scala", and on chapter 6 "types", page 123:

> The path C.super or C.super[P] where C refers to a class and P refers to a par- ent type of class C. Using the super keyword directly is shorthand for C.super. Use this path to disambiguate between identifiers defined on a class and a par- ent class.

I can't understand the `C.super[P]`, why we can specify the type `P` after `super`?

I tried this scala code:

```
class P {
   def hello = "hello from P"
}

class C extends P {
  override  def hello = "hello from C"
}

class D extends C {
  override def hello = super[P].hello
}

val d = new D
d.hello
```

Which is unable to compile on this line:

```
  override def hello = super[P].hello
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `P` must be a *parent* type, not any supertype. I.e. if you have `class D extends C with T1 with T2`, and there is a `hello` method in class `C` and traits `T1` and `T2`, just writing `super.hello` wouldn't tell the compiler which `hello` method you want. So you can write `super[C].hello`, `super[T1].hello` or `super[T2].hello`.